# Filter based on string including AND and OR arguments using regex formula on google sheets

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I want to import range based on Tags presence in the ""TAG"" column of sheet 1.

I would like to use `REGEX` as a conditional statement (eg: ""tag-1"" or ""tag-2"" and ""tag-5"") to checker if one of the tag is present in the column then filter the corresponding row.

I've tried everything `SEARCH` `FILTER` `AND` ... with any success.

`=FILTER(dataRange, REGEXMATCH(TagRange, "Tag1"), REGEXMATCH(TagRange, "Tag2"))`

returns both rows with `Tag1` and `Tag2`when I want it to behave as a `AND` operator.

`=FILTER(dataRange, AND(REGEXMATCH(TagRange, "Tag1"), REGEXMATCH(TagRange, "Tag2")))`

for this one looks like `AND()` formula returns only one value instead of mutiple `TRUE`/ `FALSE` values. So I get an error.

Google is using [RE2](http://newandroidbook.com/code/android-5.1.1_r24/external/regex-re2/doc/syntax.html) so the `?=` expression don't work

[here is the google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eoN85YkYXxBGoarTfXfo8TJDU6wBtcJoBBHzrKsy1Cw/edit#gid=633134967)

Comment: Questions on SO are not only meant to get a quick answer but they should also help others that get stuck on the same question. Could you please [edit] it so that it is self-containing?

Comment: I will edit my post when a solution is found with the solution instead of the link. Is that ok?

Comment: No, the solution goes into the answer section. But your question should be clear, have a look at [mcve]

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question, but have you tried the operators?  `+`=`OR`, `*`=`AND`.  [Help here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-use-and-or-with-google-sheets-filter-function-advanced-use/).

Comment: Thanks for the response Ron. You are talking about filter(range,(condition 1)+(condition 2)*(condition 3) correct? If so, yes I have tried that. Because regexmatch is being used it does not play nice. mismatch range sizes.

Comment: Actually that was not the issue with this idea. It is something with the import range part of it. It does not work. Unknown reason. See document, as there is a test there for this method @RonKloberdanz

Comment: Ah. I figured it out. Yeah, that method works @RonKloberdanz. Sorry I had an error in my data formatting. Thanks! 

PS> I still wish I could do it all in a regular expression because that would make the formula much more clean and reduce data management, so if someone has an idea of how to do it with regex formula/regular expressions I am all ears!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [custom formula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). This way you can use the REGEX version of Javascript and use the `?=`expression.

Here is the formula:

```
function myCustom(dataRange, rgxA) {
  rgxA = new RegExp(rgxA, "gi");
  for (var i = 0; i < dataRange.length; i++)
    dataRange[i][0] = "" + (!(dataRange[i][0].match(rgxA) == null));
  return (dataRange);
}
```

This way you will return `true`or `false` based on your Regex.
You can then enter regex like

```
((?=.*tag-1)(?=((.*tag-5)|(.*tag-2))) // tag-1 and (tag-5 or tag-2) in case insensitive
```